# Sql user define type field ignore in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I have created User define type in sql server DB and used in one table column now when i Add this table in Entity Framework, the field with this datatype is ignore and Show error message-

> Warning    2   Error 6005: The data type 'Type_Name' is currently not
>   supported for the target Entity Framework version; the column 'column_name'
>   in the table 'DB_Name' was excluded.

So how can we map our sql user define type in Entity framework, so that we can add this field with that datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a complex type in the EF designer to accomplish this.

Read here for that process:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680147.aspx

Comment: I have to map User define type with Entity Framework which is already created in DB .